# kill all processes older than x time while having pattern matching in name

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, process, kill

I want to kill all processes older than say 90 seconds. Also the names of the processes should contain "mysubstring".

I tried

```
killall -o 90s -r mysubstring
```

but it does not care about the -o parameter if there is a -r parameter. It just kills all processes which have the substring in their name including the ones running less than 90s.

Any suggestions? Especially those which do not involve excessive parsing of all different time formats of the ps command's output?

Comment: How about http://serverfault.com/a/181503/245896 ?

Comment: The answers do not work (anymore), are not portable or involve parsing different cases. Most of them involve at least two of these criteria.

Comment: Perhaps more applicable on [unix.se] - in any case, it may be helpful to specify the OS or OSes you want this to work on.  For Linux, you might want to start with `for p in $(pgrep mysubstring)"` and use the information in `/proc/$p/`.